# $_GET variable in php without using a form

Tags: php

i have gallery.php?gid=1 in gallery.php page and i have to submit data to save.php without using a form.

and i want to get the value of gid without using a button..

is that possible?

gallery.php

$gid=$_GET['gid'];

save.php

echo $gid..

Comment: What have you tried? Explain what your code is doing, and where you are actually confused.

Comment: Using get in a form simply redirects the web page to the address, which in your case would look like gallery.php?gid=WhateverInfoYouWantToPutHere. Simple answer, make a link.

Comment: if you call the script like `gallery.php?gid=1` than you can access the value with `$_GET['gid']`.

Comment: i am using adobe flash php multi uploader. i have two tables like gallery and album and those two were related by having the album_id in gallery_id. but i cant save the album_id of that gallery because of $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("location:save.php?gid=".$gid);
```

OR

use a anchor tag with `href="save.php?gid=<?php echo $gid;?>"`

Comment: actually, an anchor would be `href="save.php#anchor"`

Comment: You can make it like href="save.php?gid=<?php echo $gid;?>#anchor"

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to point out that `#anchor != Query String`.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET will contain all the variables which are in the URL, after the "?" (foo.php?gid=...).

You are not obliged to use a form to fill these variables.

Answer (score 0):

The members of  `$_GET` array is got from **query string**. In a simple way, a **query string** is tha part after the `?` character of the URL and formatted in this way:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&....
```

So you can pass any pair of key-value in to your PHP script by adding a query string to the end of this PHP file URL.